# Can I incorporate search results from my computer's files into Google Search?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to incorporate search results from the local file system into Google Search results? I'm looking for a Google Chrome extension to replace Google Desktop (which is now gone.)

Comment: It would be very easy to do this using node-webkit, but I don't think it would be feasible to incorporate node-webkit into a Chrome extension. I would need some way to invoke a shell command using Javascript, and obtain the output (perhaps using a local node.js server that would be installed as a plugin somehow).

Comment: Looking at your comment above, perhaps you might receive some useful answers on StackOverflow instead?